# I want to count and group a subset of a table

Tags: mysql, count, subset

I want to select the latest 100 rows and then count and group the result, instead of counting and grouping the whole table, but I can't figure out how to do it.

An example of how it might work (but this does not work):

```
SELECT federal_party, count(federal_party) 
    From (
SELECT federal_party 
    FROM database
    ORDER BY date_updated DESC LIMIT 100 
)
GROUP BY federal_party
```

Any idea how this would best be done?

Comment: `SELECT federal_party, count(federal_party) From ( SELECT federal_party FROM database ORDER BY date_updated DESC LIMIT 100 ) AS sub GROUP BY federal_party`